# The difference of the focal semi axes of an ellipse and a hyperbola is equal to $4$.If the ratio of their eccentricities is $\frac{3}{7}$.

Tags: conic-sections

An ellipse and a hyperbola have their principal axes along the coordinate axes and have a common foci separated by a distance $2\sqrt{13}$,the difference of their focal semi axes is equal to $4$.If the ratio of their eccentricities is $\frac{3}{7}$.Find the equation of these curves.

---

The distance between the foci of both ellipse and hyperbola is $2\sqrt{13}$.
So $2c_1=$distance between the foci of ellipse$=2\sqrt{13}$
$2c_2=$distance between the foci of hyperbola$=2\sqrt{13}$
$\frac{\text{eccentricity of ellipse}}{\text{eccentricity of hyperbola}}=\frac{3}{7}$
I do not understand what is the meaning of "the difference of their focal semi axes" and how to proceed further.

Comment: See https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20121016011336AAHN2pL

Comment: @labbhattacharjee,i did not understand after reading this link.See if $c_1=c_2$,then how is $c_1-c_2=4$ possible?

Answer (score -1):

Focal semi axis is equal to the length of the semi axis passing through focus of ellipse or hyperbole.
Focal semi axis mean same as semi major axis.
I hope you can now get answers as:
For ellipse: $a^2=49$ and $b^2=36$.
For hyperbola: $a^2=9$ and $b^2=4$
Hope it helps.